# Vim - Overwrite Plugin Scoped Function

Tags: vim

I've a plugin in *Vim* and I don't like the behavior of a single function within it. But it isn't rly a case to open a pull request, but more an extension for it.
I know that overwriting a function ist possible by using a bang as postfix, as soon as the new definition comes after the previous one. But how can I do such thing, if this method is scoped to a script within a plugin?
I wasn't able to find a hint in _Vim_s help, nor by request a search engine. Anybody aware of this topic, at least if he can say that it is simply **not** possible.

A short example:
*plugin/autoload/plugin.vim*

```
  ...
  function! s:foo() {
       // behavior I would like to adjust
  }
  ...
```

*~/.vimrc*

```
  function! foo() {
       // the "correct" behavior
  }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it is possible. But as @romainl said, you'd better suggest your patch to the plugin maintainer or ask for a variation point.

Regarding the how.

First, you'll need to identify the script number of this autoload plugin. Let's say that `:scriptname` says it's 210. In order to do that automatically I have a [`lh#askvim#scriptid()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/askvim.vim#L104)  function in my library plugin that does the job -- see the current definition at the end of the answer.

Then, to override the `s:foo()` function, you'll need to provide a new definition for

```
function! <SNR>210_Foo()
   new definition
endfunction
```

(I've just tested it with vim 8.0-1157)

IOW, we can override a script-local function. However, I haven't found how to override a script-local variable directly without a reference to its `s:` dictionary. We could inject *setter*/*getter* functions to a specific variable or a function that returns the local `s:` dictionary.

---

`lh#askvim#scriptid()` current definition is the following

```
" Function: lh#askvim#execute(command) {{{3
" @since Version 4.0.0
if exists('*execute')
  function! lh#askvim#execute(command) abort
    return split(execute(a:command), "\n")
  endfunction
else
  function! lh#askvim#execute(command) abort
    return s:beware_running_through_client_server ? [] : split(lh#askvim#exe(a:command), "\n")
  endfunction
endif

" Function: lh#askvim#scriptnames() {{{3
function! lh#askvim#scriptnames() abort
  let scripts = lh#askvim#execute('scriptnames')
  let s:scripts = map(copy(scripts), 'split(v:val, "\\v:=\\s+")')
  call lh#list#map_on(s:scripts, 1, 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":p")')
  return s:scripts
endfunction

" Function: lh#askvim#scriptid(name) {{{3
function! lh#askvim#scriptid(name, ...) abort
  let last_change = get(a:, 1, 0)
  if last_change || !exists('s:scripts')
    call lh#askvim#scriptnames()
  endif
  let matches = filter(copy(s:scripts), 'v:val[1] =~ a:name')
  if len(matches) > 1
    throw "Too many scripts match `".a:name."`: ".string(matches)
  elseif empty(matches)
    if last_change
      throw "No script match `".a:name."`"
    else
      return lh#askvim#scriptid(a:name, 1)
    endif
  endif
  return matches[0][0]
endfunction
```

Comment: Wow, thats nice! I will try it out, but so far it looks rly awesome. So far I'm not aware about the script IDs in detail. A quick search trough Vims help doesn't provide any explanation how IDs are assigned, in which case they are static and so forth. Any suggestions where I can something about this topic?

Comment: I don't know if this is documented, but here is what I've observed: every time a script is `source`d for the first time an new id (<- last id used + 1) is attributed. We can see the id with `:scriptname`, and it's used in for the internal name of `s:` functions.

Comment: Okay, and ur function does determine this generic. Interesting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible.

`s:foo()` is scoped to the script it belongs to (see `:help s:`) so it can't be accessed from anywhere else.

1. Fork it.
2. Make the desired changes to your fork.
3. Use your fork instead of the original.
4. Consider submitting a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for making this sure.